# CSS/HTML object allign center

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to put an object in the middle of HTML page. Not the perfect center. The object is a clock down and it appears in the top left part of the page. I want to set it in the top center. Is this something with the CSS or the HTML settings of the code?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When posting questions, it is helpful to include the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

> Two CSS options:
>
> put `text-align:center;` on the parent element
>
> or set a width value and `margin-left: auto;` & `margin-right:auto;`
>   on the element itself.

---

**Ok since you said top center, I assumed you didn't wan't vertical.
do this on the element:**

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 120px; /*replace with your value*/
height: 120px; /*same*/
margin-top: -60px; /*needs to be negative half size*/
margin-left: -60px; /*same*/
```

**Here's an example. Replace #test with your element.**

https://jsfiddle.net/hqpntcax/

Comment: This will only center horizontally.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am not familiar with CSS. I researched in google and tried a lot of options, but nothing successful. Your advice was really close. However, the clock down is aligned horizontally. I would need also to align it vertically. 

I checked for margin-top and margin-left, but they are not present in the code. Should I just add this options?

Comment: Yeah, you can add them. But I updated the answer to make it horizontal and vertically centered, you should use that instead. You just have to replace the pixel values with your element size and recalculate the negative margins.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark this as the correct answer so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use first google next time. have a try for [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)